# Join reputation when joining accounts

Tags: user-accounts

Would it be possible, when automatically joining my account among Stack projects, to share reputation as well?
Now I have 5 accounts and 5 different reputations - it is frustrating.
Thank you.

Comment: This question may be considered off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

This belongs to [meta](https://meta.serverfault.com/), and I voted to migrate it here, but to answer your question:

No, this is not possible. Reputation is per site. You will however gain a little reputation on new sites when you have earned sufficient reputation on one site.

From [the help](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation):

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.

Comment: I tried to put it under meta, but have low repotation for it :(